# M1Mac : rbenv install 2.6.6 Build Failed

Tags: ruby, macos, rbenv, apple-m1

When I tried to install ruby2.6.6 on my mac using rbenv, I got a "Builed Failed" message.

Initially, I ran it as follows

```
% rbenv install 2.6.6 

Downloading ruby-2.6.6.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.6.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.6.6...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.0 using ruby-build 20210825)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/zs/rjdwp8ws5_s4gjd40lj1q2gr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20210912210429.75083.Uqwy5z
Results logged to /var/folders/zs/rjdwp8ws5_s4gjd40lj1q2gr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20210912210429.75083.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
checking for x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang... (cached) x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
checking for x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-gcc... (cached) x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/zs/rjdwp8ws5_s4gjd40lj1q2gr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20210912210429.75083.Uqwy5z/ruby-2.6.6':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

As you can see in the output, "checking whether the C compiler works... no", I thought the compiler was not working properly and looked for a solution.

There is a solution to run it by specifying the GCC path, and I used that as a reference to run it as follows.

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc rbenv install 2.6.6
```

However, the result was "Build Failed".

The version of gcc is as follows

```
%gcc --version 

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

The output and log when the path of gcc is specified are as follows.

```
% CC=/usr/bin/gcc rbenv install 2.6.6

CC=/usr/bin/gcc rbenv install 2.6.6
Downloading ruby-2.6.6.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.6.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.6.6...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.0 using ruby-build 20210825)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/zs/rjdwp8ws5_s4gjd40lj1q2gr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20210912211846.75422.XoStEO
Results logged to /var/folders/zs/rjdwp8ws5_s4gjd40lj1q2gr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20210912211846.75422.log

Last 10 log lines:
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinff
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinitel
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinited
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinitef
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __darwin_fd_clr
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __darwin_fd_set
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __darwin_fd_isset
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __darwin_check_fd_set
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sputc
ln -sf ../../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin13/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.6.h include/ruby-2.6.0/x86_64-darwin13/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.6.h
```

[log file link here](https://github.com/i0li/mysite/blob/master/ruby-build.20210912211846.75422.txt)

I thought gcc was not compiling properly, so I tried reinstalling it using homebrew, but it did not work.

I'm having trouble finding a solution to this problem. If anyone can tell me what to do, I'd appreciate your response.

Answer (score 3):

YARV 2.6 is not supported on Apple Silicon.

As you can see in [the issue which is used to track which branches of YARV the fixes for Apple Silicon need to be back ported to](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/17202), 2.6 is marked as "REQUIRED", meaning it needs a back port in order to work, but this back port has not been done yet. (Compare with 2.7 which is marked as "DONE".)

> **Backport**: 2.5: UNKNOWN, 2.6: REQUIRED, 2.7: DONE

Considering that [the back port to 2.7 happened a year ago](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/17202#note-3), we can assume that the maintainers do not intend to apply it to 2.6. Which makes sense: [YARV 2.6 is in "security maintenance" status](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/branches/), which means only security fixes are done, and this is not a security issue.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Oh, I see. So does that mean that 2.7 is supported and can be installed?

Answer (score 1):

The solution on [this blog post](https://brandur.org/fragments/ruby-3-on-m1) worked for me. The author suggested:

```rb
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-readline-dir="$(abrew --prefix readline)" rbenv install 3.0.0
```

But as it mentions that you no longer need to load different versions of Homebrew for Intel/M1 Macs, you no longer need to set `abrew` and `ibrew`. So, what worked for me was:

```rb
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-readline-dir="$(brew --prefix readline)" rbenv install 2.6.6
```

Note the simple change from `abrew` to `brew`.

Comment: This was working for me: 
`RUBY_CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rbenv install 2.6.6`

Comment: For installing 2.4.4 I needed to use `RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-readline-dir="$(brew --prefix readline)" RUBY_CFLAGS=-DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC rbenv install 2.4.4`

Comment: Neither the answer nor the first comment worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

possible to install using below link on m1  RUBY_CFLAGS=-DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC rbenv install 2.6.6  https://almonta2021blog.com/%E3%80%90ruby%E3%80%91m1-mac%E3%81%A7ruby%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B/

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score -2):

I had success installing 2.6.3 with the following

```
CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration -Wcompound-token-split-by-macro" rbenv install 2.6.3
```

Source: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1725#issuecomment-927446555